# PHP Session variable lost after refresh / redirect

Tags: php, session, redirect, authentication, session-variables

I am making login page and everything works fine, but while refreshing secure page or redirecting to another page variable disappears.

**Login:**

```
<?php session_start(); 

//connection to database and other stuff

if ($user == $dbuser && $pass == $dbpass) {

    $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
    $_SESSION['authenticated'] = "yes";
    $suser = $_SESSION['user']; //just to test if session works

}

?>
```

**Secure page:**

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

//small amount of html here

<?php
    $suser = $_SESSION['user'];
    $sauth = $_SESSION['authenticated'];

    if ($sauth != 'yes') { //not completed yet (needs user name check)
        echo "<a href='./'>Log in</a> first!";
        require ('./login.php');
        die;
    } else {
    //not so important code here
    }
?>

//rest of html here
```

I didn't notice any mistakes and error log file is clean so it must be something else. Session works fine after redirecting to secure page but as I said earlier refresh of page or another redirect clears session variables.

Page: http://nano.filiparag.com/admin/
If you want to test it just ask for username and password

**Note:**
Now I tried doing this with `setcookie()` and it didn't work again

---

#### Solved

The problem was in logout button. I made separate PHP file for it and now everything works fine.

Comment: Are `$dbuser` and `$dbpass` always defined? If they aren't, then that `if` block would return true since all 4 variables could be undefined/falsey. That would overwrite your `$_SESSION['user']` and `$_SESSION['authenticated']` values.

Comment: @jraede Don't worry about db* because they are always defined - picked up from database.

Comment: Are you positive? From your code that's the only thing I can see that would log the person out. Posting more code might help, as would an explanation of how you redirect them to the secure page after logging in.

Comment: @jraede Database connection is code above if statement in Login page. They get message 'Loged in as example' and an link to click for redirection. Login form calls (action) itself (same file).

Comment: check if the session id is changing. if it is the cookie is not set in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try using this

Login:

```
<?php session_start(); 
ob_start();
//connection to database and other stuff

if ($user == $dbuser && $pass == $dbpass) {

    $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
    $_SESSION['authenticated'] = "yes";
    $suser = $_SESSION['user']; //just to test if session works

}

?>
```

Secure page:

```
<?php session_start(); 
  ob_start();?>

//small amount of html here
<?php session_start(); ob_start();
    $suser = $_SESSION['user'];
    $sauth = $_SESSION['authenticated'];

    if ($sauth != 'yes') { //not completed yet (needs user name check)
        echo "<a href='./'>Log in</a> first!";
        require ('./login.php');
        die;
    } else {
    //not so important code here
    }
?>

//rest of html here
```

Comment: Still same. Variables disappear

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing that your `login.php` scripts is doing something with the session variables when you include it. Can I have a look at your `login.php` script and I'll edit my answer then

Comment: I already found what was wrong. Anyway, thanks for answering!